# Selenium Driver Chrome 111 - not working in headless mode

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

It seems to be that Selenium Chrome driver stopped working with Chrome 111 in headless mode.

I applied the recommended

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
```

settings, but it only works if

```
--headless
```

chrome driver argument not applied. Otherwise it gives:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
```

Is there any solution to use selenium with Chrome 111 in headless mode?

Comment: Did you try using `--headless=new` ?

Comment: Yes, but did not work, same error message

Comment: What do you get when manually running chrome with __chrome-path__+`--headless=new --remote-allow-origins=* `?

Comment: Issue was caused by a typo on another argument - that typo was there before Chrome 111 as well, but after this there must be a stronger validation on arguments which caused this issue

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test04_Headless {
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--headless=new");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://selenium.dev");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    driver.quit();
}
```

}